# readable version of wp_query output

Tags: php

Trying to study the output of some wp objects, and it's hard to read for example the output of `print_r($wp_query);` I wonder if there is a way to auto format, beutify these outputs for a better readability?

Comment: Use the `<pre>` tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756842/what-does-php-echo-pre-echo-pre-mean

Comment: My personal favorite is `printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $wp_query, 1 ) );`